# Proving that $\dim T^{-1}(E) = \dim(\operatorname{Ker}T) + \dim (\operatorname{Ker}T\cap\operatorname{Im}(T))$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

[image]

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}$
My work: I know that  $\dim(T^{-1}(E)) = \dim(\Ker T^{-1}(E)) + \dim(\Im(T^{-1}(E)))$.

I was able to show that $\Ker(T^{-1}(E)) \subseteq \Ker(T)$ and $\Ker (T)\subseteq \Ker (T^{-1}(E))$
and so $\Ker(T^{-1}(E))= \Ker(T)$ but I don't know how to go ahead with the second bit. I want to show that $\Ker( T) \cap \Im(T) = \Im(T^{-1}(E))$. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Your question is not the same as  the question in the picture. Where  has $E$ gone?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your formula has no `E`. Further, the dimension of an operator like $ˆT^{-1}$ is meaningless.

Comment: I see what you mean. Edited!

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Comment: Partly. What's the kernel of $T^{-1}(E)$? It's a subspace, it has no kernel.

Comment: To be honest i'm pretty confused about the whole topic. I just used the formula that says that for a linear transformation F: U > W    dim(F)= dim(Ker(F))+ dim (Im(F))

Comment: More exactly, it's $\dim \color{red}U=\cdots$.  It's called the *rank-nullity theorem*.

Comment: can you point out where i'm going wrong here and how I should tackle the question?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

To prove that $\; \dim T^{-1}(E) = \dim(\operatorname{Ker}T) + \dim (E\cap\operatorname{Im}(T))$, consider the *restriction* of the linear map $T$ to $T^{-1}(E)$, which may be denoted $T_E$, and apply the *rank nullity formula* to this restriction. You'll have to show that

- $\operatorname{Ker}(T_E)=\operatorname{Ker}(T)$;
- $\operatorname{Im}(T_E)=E\cap\operatorname{Im}(T)$.

Comment: What is the restriction?

Comment: The restriction of a function to a subset is obtained when you take the subset as domain, instead of the whole set. For instance, we may say that *the restriction of* $\cos$ *to the interval* $[0,\pi]$ *is a decreasing bijection from this interval to* $[-1,1]$.